# Disable collection with python or mel

Tags: python, render, maya, mel

I am creating render layers through python for Maya 2022's render setup and cannot find any documentation to disable a collection inside a render layer using python or mel. Basic code below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Craig

```
`rs = renderSetup.instance()  
rl = rs.createRenderLayer(render_layer_name)

#create collections
c1 = rl.createCollection("wanted_meshes")
c1.getSelector().setPattern(str(add_wildcard_list))

c2 = rl.createCollection("unwanted meshes")
c2.getSelector().setPattern(str(subtract_wildcard_list))

#code snippet to disable c2 wanted here`
```

I am unsure what snippet of code to use in order to disable the collection called 'c2'

Comment: `c2.setSelfEnabled(False)`